# dojo Grid Json issue

Tags: json, dojo, grid

I have this code

```
dojo.ready(function(){
  inventoryStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest({
    target: "http://localhost:9080/driver/dojoMVC",
    idProperty: "name",
    put: function(object, options){
      if(object.quantity < 0){
    throw new Error("quantity must not be negative");
      }
    }
});
results = inventoryStore.query("");
var storeData =  new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ 
  data:dojo.fromJson(results)
});

gridLayout = [
  { name: 'Name', field: 'name', editable: true},
  { name: 'Quantity', field: 'quantity'},
  { name: 'Category', field: 'category'}];
var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
  store: storeData,
  clientSort: true, 
  structure: gridLayout
}, dojo.byId("gridElement"));
grid.startup();
```

When i run it i receive this strange error in FF console

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
[Break On This Error]   

([object Object])

json.js (line 26, col 9)
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Which line does it blow up on?? What does the content of storeData look like??

Comment: The error is in json.js which is dojo base file. The storeData is JSON format {"name" : "name_val", "quantity" : "quantity_val" , "category" : "category_val"}

Comment: I meant which line of your code? inventoryStore.query? new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore?? or new dojox.grid.DataGrid?

Comment: Sorry! the error is on this declaration var storeData =  new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ data:dojo.fromJson(results) });

Comment: Try putting dojo.fromJson(results) in its own variable and examine the contents to make sure the data looks ok. var tmp = dojo.fromJson(results); alert(tmp);

Comment: results = inventoryStore.query("");
var data = dojo.fromJson(results);
alert(data);
var storeData =  new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ 
  data: data
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you must setup your Layout like this :

```
        var layout = [[
            {name:"Id", field: "ident", width:"30%"},
            {name:"Name", field: "name", width:"70%"}
            ]];
```

In Ev'ry Example i find in dojo the layout is in double brackets.
This would explain why the Error says " missing ]".

Look:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore.html?highlight=itemfilewritestore#itemfilewritestore-changes-reflected-in-dojox-data-datagrid

**Update1**

so the Error lies in the store. Have you tried to fill in the data like:

```
results = inventoryStore.query( name : "*"); // to query all items
```

Have you checked it there are any results in "results"?

```
var storeData =  new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ 
                 data:results
                 });
```

After all i would try to fill in the data without dojo.fromJson.

Give it a try.

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answer ... but this is not the cause. Like i told to GoinOff the error is above the layout declaration at the  var storeData = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ data:dojo.fromJson(results) }); Anyway ... i put the double brackets and still the same error.

Comment: Using the query as you mention didn't bring any changes to the behavior. And yes, i have data in storeData object. I can see that in FF console and also i made a custom function to iterate through the object.

Comment: So i have no further Ideas - maybe this would help you to solve it on your own : http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/17/json-referencing-in-dojo/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside the code you posted, which has a syntax error at the very end around line 26. You started with `dojo.ready({` but didn't finish it with `});`

Here, reformatted to make it more obvious:

```
dojo.ready(function(){
    inventoryStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest({
        target: "http://localhost:9080/driver/dojoMVC",
        idProperty: "name",
        put: function(object, options){
            if(object.quantity < 0){
                throw new Error("quantity must not be negative");
            }
        }
    });
    results = inventoryStore.query("");
    var storeData =  new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ 
        data:dojo.fromJson(results)
    });

    gridLayout = [
        { name: 'Name', field: 'name', editable: true},
        { name: 'Quantity', field: 'quantity'},
        { name: 'Category', field: 'category'}
    ];
    var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        store: storeData,
        clientSort: true, 
        structure: gridLayout
    }, dojo.byId("gridElement"));

    grid.startup();
```

Try adding:

```
});
```

Also, you're missing some `var` keywords in there.

Comment: Hello! The mistake was made here when i copy-paste the code. There is end tag in my code. Also i do not think there the problems is caused by var keywords.

Comment: Probably not your current issue, but proper use of `var` is very important and preventing certain types of hard-to-find bugs.